# Why would max-width not work on this?

Tags: html, button, css

Using plain old CSS, why won't 'max-width' not work on the following:

```
button {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 540px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
}
```

The wrapper for this element:

```
#wrapper {
  max-width: 1024px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**EDIT**

Code added to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BXdrG/

Comment: Can you recreate this in [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: it's working just fine http://jsfiddle.net/ATAnj/

Comment: jsFiddle added and @ZoltanToth it doesn't work fine when you just have one word for a button

Comment: It's working how it should work. `max-width` is not `width`. The tag is self explaining.

Comment: `max-width` doesn't mean it will stretch to 540px all the time. If you want the button have some width you have to assign that width ( or min-width )

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ah ok, I misunderstood its use. To get a fluid button that won't stretch to massive sizes I added the following:

```
width:100%;
max-width: 540px;
```

Thanks commenters!

Comment: Is it necessary to make "width:100%" in order to use max-width?

Answer (score 58):

For `max-width` to work correctly, your element first needs a certain `width`. Use **100%** to achieve what you want. See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/QsHa9/

Comment: bro you are lifesaver i was trying to use maxwidth in flexbox and in flexbox the spacebetween property was not working somehow the width of the flexbox was shrinking down and it was almost like 2-3 hour i was stuck on this problem. Thankyou for your post

Comment: Is it necessary to make "width:100%" in order to use max-width?

Comment: Not enough in my case. It has a definitive width, but the max-width has no effect. `overflow: hidden` also doesn't work. The browser dev tools show that the div is wider than the viewport, regardless of `max-width: 20px` or `max-width calc(100svh - 20px)`. Edit: My problem was that a `min-width` was applied to it, which apparently took precedence. Corrected with `min-width: min(500px, calc(100svh - 20px))` instead of `min-width: 500px`

Answer (score 7):

```
button {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 540px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;

  width:100%; /* you forgot this */
}
```