# How to scale multiple <div> dynamically using min- and max-width?

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of divs with a specific height. I want the width to scale from 2rem to 2.75 rem, dependent on the available space. It's probably a noobie question but I just can't figure out how to do this - I already tried using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14939612/2725515), but the divs don't resize. The desired behaviour is:

- each of the div elements use max-width, when there is enough space
- when there is not enough space to fit all divs with min-space inside, they should wrap
- in between those two cases, they should resize equally

HTML:

```
<div class="pagination-number--demo-multiple-numbers">
    <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
        42
    </div>
    ... (more elements)
```

CSS:

```
.pagination-number--demo-multiple-numbers {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.pagination-number {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0.0625rem solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.pagination-number--smaller {
  height: 2.25rem;
  line-height: 2.125rem;
}
.pagination-number--narrow-to-wide {
  min-width: 2rem;
  max-width: 2.75rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.pagination-number--active {
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q5omjujd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this simply with Flexbox. Just add this to your CSS with the following two updated classes

**CSS**

```
.pagination-number--demo-multiple-numbers {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.pagination-number {
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    border: 0.0625rem solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```css
.pagination-number--demo-multiple-numbers {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.pagination-number {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  border: 0.0625rem solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}
.pagination-number--smaller {
  height: 2.25rem;
  line-height: 2.125rem;
}
.pagination-number--narrow-to-wide {
  min-width: 2rem;
  max-width: 2.75rem;
  width: 100%;
}
.pagination-number--active {
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination-number--demo-multiple-numbers">
  <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
    42
  </div>
  <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
    42
  </div>
  <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
    42
  </div>
  <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
    42
  </div>
  <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
    42
  </div>
  <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
    42
  </div>
  <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
    42
  </div>
  <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
    42
  </div>
  <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
    42
  </div>
  <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
    42
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using viewport measuring unit for width and borders of the div boxes. Also you cant use width and max-width together as the element will always conform to the max-width value. Use the following css updated classes and i think you will get what you want.

```
.pagination-number {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0.05vw solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.pagination-number--narrow-to-wide {
   min-width: 2rem;
   /* For width: (Full viewport width - Total box border(0.5 *  10) / Total number of div boxes (10) = > 100vw-5vw => 95vw / 10 */
   width: calc(95vw /10); 
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```css
.pagination-number--demo-multiple-numbers {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.pagination-number {
      font-size: 0.875rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0.05vw solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.pagination-number--smaller {
  height: 2.25rem;
  line-height: 2.125rem;
}
.pagination-number--narrow-to-wide {
   min-width: 2rem;
   width: calc(95vw /10); /* (Full viewport width - Total box border(0.5 * 10) / Total number of div boxes (10) = > 100vw-5vw => 95vw / 10 */
   margin: 0 auto;
}
.pagination-number--active {
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination-number--demo-multiple-numbers">
    <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
        42
    </div>
    <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
        42
    </div>
    <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
        42
    </div>
    <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
        42
    </div>
    <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
        42
    </div>
    <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
        42
    </div>
    <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
        42
    </div>
    <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
        42
    </div>
    <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
        42
    </div>
    <div class="pagination-number
        pagination-number--smaller
        pagination-number--narrow-to-wide
        pagination-number--active
        ">
        42
    </div>
</div>
```