# Max width is not working on a input wrapped Inside a Div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I created a Search Bar and wrapped it inside a div and have given it the max-width of 500px (100% with to the search Input) but don't know why max width is not working and I search the Stack Overflow and found a link [Why would max-width not work on this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938428/why-would-max-width-not-work-on-this) and tried this but it didn't worked for me

So can anyone please tell me why its not working and how to make it work :)

Any kind of help is highly Appreciated

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  font-family:arial;
}
header{
  width: 100%;
  padding:20px 20px;
}
nav{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
}
.menu-container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
  position:relative;
}
.search-input-container{
  width:100%;
  max-width:500px;
}
input[type="search"]{
  border-radius:500px;
  padding:5px 10px;
  width:100%;
}

ul li{
  list-style:none;
}
ul{
  margin:10px;
}
button{
  outline:none;
  border:none;
  padding:8px 15px;
}

a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
.submenu-items{
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>

      <!--  Logo Wrapper -->
      <div class="logo">
        <a href=""><img src="" alt="Test Logo"></a>
      </div>



      <!--  Search Wrapper || Issue Area-->
      <div class="search-container">

        <form action="get">

          <div class="search-input-container">
            
         
            <input type="search" class="search">
            
          </div>

        </form>

      </div>
      <!--  Search Wrapper Ends ↑ -->
      
      

      <div class="menu-container">
        <ul>

          <li>
            <a href="">Help</a>
            
          </li>

        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="">Campagians</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="buttons-container">
        <a href="#"><button class="Login-btn">Log in</button></a>

        <a href="#"><button class="signup-btn">Sign up</button></a>

      </div>

    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What width do you want it to be? Max-width means that's the maximum, but it doesn't mean it will actually get there.

Comment: Are you looking for a minimum width of 500PX, perhaps?

Comment: @RolandoYera Thanks for your Reply I want the search bar to be actually maximum 500px not bigger than that

Comment: Want you that your search covers a complete line, but it is not bigger than 500px?

Comment: I guess my question is, what's the minimum size you want it to be?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `max-width`, try using `width: clamp()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()))

I think in your case it would be something like:

```css
.search-input-container {
  width: clamp(150px, 400px, 500px);
}
```

Here 150px is the minimal size,
400px - is the ideal size, that the element wants to be,
and 500px - is the maximum possible size. so it can't grow bigger then that.

That way the input will try to be 400px, but if there is no space - it will shrink down up to 150px.